Azure Logic App, Run history: How to see a parameter from within the runs?
This concerns the Run history tab in the overview page of a Logic App within a ressource group. Our company has many of these in prod, and often need to go back and find specific runs. This is why it would be a game changer for us to be able to filter based on information within the actual run. To give an example, let's say a logic app deals with a car and knows the registration number. It would be nice to be able to go into run-history and filter based on registration numbers, but after hours of googling and trying I have been defeated, I can't do it.

It's this page here, it seems like there is no way to add another column for instance. The Identifier is automatically generated before the run actually starts and as best I can tell cannot be changed at all. How can I filter through the run history using a registration number, which is held as a variable in run-time for the logic app?
As a quick bonus:
The similar yet outside of Azure application called Power Automate has this functionality build in to it in a super intuitive way. You simply press add column and it will give you an overview of variables that are available:

How can I achieve anything similar in Azure?

You can use tracked properties in logic app to filter based on a specific field

While you cannot filter the Logic App runs by the car registration number, you can use tracked properties in your Logic Apps. For example, you can add the car registration number as a tracked property - it will be logged in Log Analytics along with other information about your Logic App runs, including the run ID, which will allow you to map the car registration number to the run ID. You will still need to filter the runs by their IDs though as you do now.
The tracked properties will be added as new columns in the AzureDiagnostics table. You will find them when you filter the table by Category == "WorkflowRuntime" and check the columns.
